# About Azure Backup

Tags: azure, backup, azure-backup-vault

I have a weekly incremental backup with Azure Backup.
What happens to this backup if the previous backup was not completed at the start of the backup? Twice
(Will this backup start after it is interrupted and the previous backup is complete, or will it be aborted and run?)

Regards,

Comment: Adding to @sumanthMarigowda's answer. You might encounter an error while performing Azure disk backups - "UserErrorMaxConcurrentOperationLimitReached" if the maximum number of allowed concurrent Backups has reached. In that case, please wait until the previous running Backup completes, and start the new backup operation.

Answer (score 0):

Is this manual backup or automatic backup? Azure vm or Azure sql db? What kind of backups? – If I cancel a backup job after it starts, is the transferred backup data deleted?
No. All data that was transferred into the vault before the backup job was canceled remains in the vault.

Azure Backup uses a checkpoint mechanism to occasionally add checkpoints to the backup data during the backup.
Because there are checkpoints in the backup data, the next backup process can validate the integrity of the files.
The next backup job will be incremental to the data previously backed up. Incremental backups only transfer new or changed data, which equates to better utilization of bandwidth.
If you cancel a backup job for an Azure VM, any transferred data is ignored. The next backup job transfers incremental data from the last successful backup job.

This article answers common questions about the Azure Backup service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-backup-faq